# Change style of n items after selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a group of radio buttons with labels.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{
  color:red;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label~label{
  font-weight:bold;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label~label:nth-of-type(-n+3){
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>A</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>B</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>C</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>D</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>E</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>F</label>
</div>
```

When I select a radio button I'd like the next three items have a style applied to them.

However, if you run the snippet, you will see that my code only highlights the first three items in the div, not the first three items after the selection.

How can I get the style applied to the first three items after the selection?

Basically I want the following to happen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *ugly* working solution (if I consider the case that you cannot change your html structure) :

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{
  color:red;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label~label{
  font-weight:bold;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label+br+input+label{
  background-color:green;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label+br+input+label+br+input+label{
  background-color:green;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label+br+input+label+br+input+label+br+input+label{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>A</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>B</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>C</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>D</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>E</label><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="group1"><label>F</label>
</div>
```